# web worker Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I have a web worker, refer below.

```
var worker_script = function(){
        self.onmessage = function(e){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 postMessage(xhttp.responseText);
                 counter = 0;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET",e.data, true);
            xhttp.send();

        }   
    }

var search_worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["("+worker_script.toString()+")()"], {type: 'text/javascript'})));
// post message to worker
search_worker.postMessage("https://www.connectnigeria.com/ajax/getkeywords?keyword=");
search_worker.onmessage = function(e){
console.log(e);
};
```

this is working in my local server but in my production server, it gives me this error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
>   Invalid URL at self.onmessage
>   (blob:https://mywebsitesample.com/d17ebd88-7452-4282-9313-26d697fea457:1:198)

what could be the problem? any ideas?

Comment: it's odd, because this is client code, so the server should be irrelevant - I'm guessing it's either a typo, or some text encoding issue with your js file

Comment: updated. please see again my post.